# Is "far + adjective + than" a correct variant of "far more + adjective + than"?

Tags: comparative-constructions

Starting from a locution similar to "far more dangerous than...", I wonder if the "more" can be omitted, as in "far dangerous than".

I suspect that's not standard English, but it seems to be quite common on the Internet.

What do the native speakers here think?

Comment: no, you can't omit it there.

Comment: No: the 'far' qualifies 'more'. You can say "It is more dangerous".

Comment: "it seems to be quite common on the Net" - don't forget that English is not the first language of many people on the Internet!

Comment: That's the **problem with Google**. It makes many things **seem** ok when they are not. And not just grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use “far” as an adverb to intensify an adjective in comparative form

> A horse is far swifter than a slug.

But this adverbial use of “far” is not itself a way to form comparatives.

> A horse is far swift than a slug

is simply ungrammatical.

Adjectives longer than three syllables (and some shorter) do not generally have a comparative form. We say “more beautiful” rather than “beautifuler.” We say “more skillful” rather than “skillfuller.” We can and do use “far” with the **correct** comparative form to intensify a comparative

> Greta Garbo was a far more beautiful woman than Bette Davis, but a far less skillful actress

Answer (score 1):

The basic comparison is "more dangerous than..." "Far" simply amplifies "more."

You can do this in other situations where you have "More + adjective + than etc"

Ex. Your new job is far more interesting than what you were doing before.

However, with the construction "adjective -er than..." it seems a bit awkward to amplify the comparative adjective with "far":

It is far hotter today than yesterday.
That country is far bigger than the other country.

These two sentences seem a bit odd, although native speakers would understand them. They would be better written with "much" in place of "far":

It is much hotter today than yesterday.
That country is much bigger than the other country.

Comment: I find _far hotter_ and _far bigger_ quite natural. (British English).

Comment: Agreed, "far hotter" and "far bigger" are fine. But "far dangerous than" is simply incorrect.

Comment: @SteveBennett - Yes, because _dangerouser_ isn't a word.

Answer (score 0):

"far more dangerous" is exactly the same as "much more dangerous".

It is an adverb that modifies the adjective more.